# how to execute c file in minix operating system

Tags: c, unix, compilation, minix

Could someone explain to me what is  `a.out` and how it works?
This is the first time I am using Unix (minix).
I have one folder with two files `filename.c` and `test.sh` (containing three lines starting with ./a.out and some f=values).
I just want to compile and execute `filename.c` if it is not?

Comment: ./a.out 5 0 100 5000&
./a.out 6 0 100 5000&
./a.out 7 1 100 5000&

Answer (score 1):

I don't use minux, so take it with a grain of salt, but it seems you should be using `mcc` for compilation*:

```
mcc filename.c -o myprogram
chmod +x myprogram
./myprogram
```

The `-o` option allows you to pick the exectable name so it's not defaulted to `a.out`, the `chmod +x` is to make sure that you have a valid exectuable (it might not be needed, but it won't hurt)

[*Reference](http://diuf.unifr.ch/pai/education/2002_2003/courses/OS/Minixlab.pdf)

Comment: it is clang - i just found it

Comment: @user2085339 - Awesome! good find.

Answer (score 1):

I use ubuntu and compile using gcc.First i write the code and say I named it testing.c .Then I save it in a folder say c.
then i go command line and if currently I m not in the folder c I change it to folder c by writing

```
cd /c
```

then i compile it using gcc

```
gcc testing.c -o testing
```

then next i rung it by typing

```
./testing
```

note:-this is what i do on ubuntu when compiling using gcc.

Answer (score 0):

-> To compile after saving and exiting the program(ESC :wq)
at command prompt the command is CC 
(Your filename needs to have an extension .C)

->To run the program at command prompt you need to type 
./a.out.

->To compile and run without closing your program
it is (ESC) :!CC % and (ESC) :!./a.out

U can have a look at  [here](http://www.unix.com/programming/6382-how-compile-run-c-programs-unix-environment.html)

Comment: i am using minix and cc or CC is not a valid  command

Answer (score 0):

The Unix custom is that if you call a compiler to generate an executable, and do not give the name of the executable explicitly, the executable is called `a.out` (presumably for assembler output). So:

- `cc -c program.c`: Just compile, gives `program.o`
- `cc program.c`: Compile and link, no executable name given, executable is `a.out`
- `cc -o name program.c`: Compile and link, asked explicitly to give executable `name`

The compilers usually are smart enough to divine the contents (and thus how to handle files) from their extensions.